# Why the same zip file doesn't work in MacOS?

Tags: macos, zip, unzip

This is quite strange for me. I have an APP file (.app) which works on my MacOS. I want to upload it into the AWS S3 so I zip it as .app file is considered as a folder. When I download the zip file and unzip it, the app doesn't work anymore.
I even tried zipping it in terminal

```
zip -yr myapp.zip myapp.app
```

And when I download it, I also tried unzipping it in terminal

```
unzip myapp.zip -d myapp-folder
```

But that was also doesn't work. I checked the app size and they are identical. Any idea why it happens? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`zip`/`unzip` don't preserve file attributes (including extended attributes). To fix this, use `ditto` tool instead of `zip`/`unzip`.
The same rule for just copying files: use `ditto` instead of `cp`

Comment: I tried `ditto -ck --rsrc --keepParent --sequesterRsrc folder file.zip` and
`ditto -c -k --sequesterRsrc --keepParent AppName.app AppName.zip` but it is still the same. After it gets uploaded to the S3 and then download it, it does not work. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Amin how do you unpack downloaded zip?

Comment: To unpack, I either double click on the zip file or by terminal it would be unzip command: `unzip myapp.zip -d myapp-folder` . Any other way that I could do that?